# Elasticsearch sync database recommended / standard strategy

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm pondering a strategy to maintain an index for Elasticsearch, I've found a [plugin](https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-river-jdbc) which may handle maintenance quite well however I would like to get a little more intimate with Elasticsearch since I really like her and the plugin would make playtime a little less intimate if you know what I mean.

So anyway, if I have a data set that would have fairly frequent updates (say ~ 1 update / 10s), would I run into performance problems with Elasticsearch? Can partial index updates be done when a single row changes or is a full re-rebuild of the index necessary? The strategy I plan on implementing involves modifying the index whenever I do CRUD with my application (python postgre) so there will be some overhead with the code which I'm not overly concerned about, just the performance. Is my strategy common?

I've used Sphinx which did have partial re-indexing which was run with a cron job to keep in sync, it had mapping between indexes and MySQL tables defined in the config. This was the recommended approach for Sphinx. Is there a recommended approach with Elasticsearch?

Comment: just indexing a new document (the hierarchy is index/type/document) is fine and should come with no malus; quite common is also the use of [rivers](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/rivers/current/index.html) like e.g. the [jdbc river](https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-river-jdbc)

Comment: rivers is now deprecated.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are a number of different strategies for handling this, there's no simple one size fits all solution.

To answer some of your questions, first, there is no such thing as a partial update in Elasticsearch/Lucene. If you update a single field in a document the whole document is rewritten. Be aware of the performance implications of this when designing your schema. If you update a single document however, it should be available near instantly. Elasticsearch is a near-realtime search engine, you don't have to worry about regenerating the index constantly.

For your write load one update / 10s the default performance settings should be fine. That's a very low write load for ES in fact, it can scale much higher. Netflix, for instance, performs 7 millions updates / minute in one of their clusters.

As far as syncing strategies go, I've written an in-depth article on this ["Keeping Elasticsearch in Sync"](https://www.found.no/foundation/keeping-elasticsearch-in-sync/)